# c++ change cin maybe skipline?

Tags: c++, string, cin

I'm starting with C++ in college (before used Modula2). I have problems with cin.
While interacting with the user, I need to recognize certain "commands".,

For example "addClient Rafael". I handle it the following way
 cin >> command, strcoll (command, "addClient"), and then, if command equals addClient, y do
cin >> command2 (so I read Rafael),. and do the proper procedures...

But also, I have to recognize "deleteAll" which deletes all my database, so I dont have to read the second parameter.

When someone enters random things such as "skjdsjfnsdj" its supossed to say "Wrong command" for which, if command didnt equal none of my "known" commands it printf "wrong command".

The problem is, when some types "skajskajs jakasjkajs" it says "wrong command. worng command"... it should only say it once...

So, "noskip" i thing is no use, maybe if i could break the string.., maybe a simpler way, help anyone?

Comment: Please show your code. It sounds like you should use std::getline, but it's hard to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible and intuitive way to do this is as follows:

```
bool done = false;
while( !done ) {
    string commandLine, cmd, value;
    getline( cin, commandLine );

    istringstream ss(commandLine);
    ss >> cmd >> value;

    if( cmd == "deleteAll" ) {
        // BOOM
    }
    else if( cmd == "addClient" ) {
        // Do something with 'value'.  You could wait until here to read it
        // if you want, instead of always attempting to read it.
    }
    else if( cmd == "quit" ) {
        done = true;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Wrong command\n";
    }
}
```

Or edit to suit your purposes.  I use this sort of approach for parsing simple key/value pair config files.  Works a treat, and takes almost no effort to code.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply try [istream::getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) instead.

It will prevent the message appearing more than once for each command (separated by a *\n*).

Comment: I'd always suggest `std::getline` (from <string>) first, unless I knew of a reason to prefer the more cumbersome `istream::getline`.

Comment: Yes, but if typed "addClient Rafael", it would get "addClientRafael", wouldn't it?

Comment: It will give you the line as it is typed in so if the space was there it will be in the buffer. The only additional thing you will have do is parse the input so you can get hold of the parameter (in this case 'Rafael').

Comment: @eq- I didn't know about that one. I just keep to the stdin approach. I shall have to look at that.